# Saving captured video to iOS library with CameraManager & Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file, camera

I imported [CameraManager](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CameraManager) in a Swift project to easily capture video in my app. But I'm not sure how to export the captured video to my iOS folder following this code :

```
cameraManager.stopVideoRecording({ (videoURL, error) -> Void in
NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(videoURL, toURL: 
self.myVideoURL, error: &error)
})
```

In Swift 4, I needed this updated code :

```
cameraManager.stopVideoRecording({ (videoURL, error) -> Void in
        FileManager.default.copyItem(at: videoURL, to: self.videoURL)
    })
```

I think I need to change this value but...

```
self.videoURL
```

If anyone could help !

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

CameraManager is not providing any out of the box API to save the video to the iOS library (as of latest version 4.3.0).

However, Once the video is taken - it gives the URL for the video file and we can save that video to the library easily by using Apple's `Photos` API.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.videoURL)
}) { saved, error in
    if saved {
        // Video saved successfully
    }
}
```

Don't forgot to import `Photos` and add `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` to your `info.plist`

More info can be found from SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482738/swift-save-video-from-nsurl-to-user-camera-roll)